# Class Instantiation Java

Tags: java, class, instantiation

```
I i = new A();
```

Why can we use interface I to instantiate object of class A? Shouldn't we be using A obj=new A()?

```
interface I {
    void f();
    void g();
}

class A implements I {
    public void f() { System.out.println("A: doing f()"); }
    public void g() { System.out.println("A: doing g()"); }
}

class B implements I {
    public void f() { System.out.println("B: doing f()"); }
    public void g() { System.out.println("B: doing g()"); }
}

class C implements I {
// delegation
    I i = new A();

    public void f() { i.f(); }
    public void g() { i.g(); }

    // normal attributes
    public void toA() { i = new A(); }
    public void toB() { i = new B(); }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what the question/problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can we use reference variable of type 'I' to refer to object of type 'A'?

Because `A implements I` (verbatim quote from your code).

`A` does everything specified by the interface `I`, so it's compatible with the declared type `I` of the reference. Through interfaces and inheritance, objects can have multiple types.

Comment: So does I behave as a superclass (parent) of A?

Answer (score 1):

It is because A is of type I since it implements the I interface.